# Develop multilingual windows application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, multilingual

I am asking about the common techniques which are used in c# to support multilingual interface in windows forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything I said here:

[Internationalizing Desktop App within a couple years... What should we do now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270829/internationalizing-desktop-app-within-a-couple-years-what-should-we-do-now)

applies to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend to check out this tool: [Multilizer](http://www.multilizer.com/).
I have been using it in my CBuilder/Delphi projects.

Comment: As I'm always on the look-out for improved translated interfaces, I was wondering what made you decide to use this tool? I had a quick glance at the site and didn't get answers to most of my questions (how to handle long strings, handle LTR vs RTL vs TTB etc)

Comment: It supported C++ Builder and worked well.
What's the difference how long the strings are? They must be translated anyway - and Multilizer actually shows with color coding if your translated string gets much longer than original.
And I didn't need any fancy settings - just Baltic languages,Russian.

Answer (score 0):

You should use resources files. Check [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t18274tk.aspx) for example.