# Change Language in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multilingual, cultureinfo

I am developing a multilingual program in C# on Windows

How to change Windows writing language on certain actions...

 e.g. to change from English to Arabic on focus event.

Thanks

Comment: These similar post may shed some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397356/develop-multilingual-windows-application-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270829/internationalizing-desktop-app-within-a-couple-years-what-should-we-do-now Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To select a whole new culture, set the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to a new culture, e.g. to set to French:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

You can find a list of the predefined `CultureInfo` names [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110313021717/http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/globalization/demos/CultureInfo.aspx) and [here](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm).

If you want to change certain aspects of the default culture, you can grab the current thread's culture, use it it's name to create a new CultureInfo instance and set the thread's new culture with some changes, e.g. to change the current culture to use the 'Euro' symbol:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Comment: For some situations it is also necessary to set System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture. (Note the "UI" in the middle of the property name.)

Comment: I had to set the UICulture also while running unit tests. Comment above saved me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = yournewculture;
```

Also see the `CurrentUICulture` property.

Comment: Can you please state how to get "yournewculture"

Answer (score 3):

In load Event insert the code below:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =
      InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition, if you want to refresh all the controls' resources at runtime, you will need to use something like this:

```
private void RefreshResources(Control ctrl, ComponentResourceManager res)
{
    ctrl.SuspendLayout();
    res.ApplyResources(ctrl, ctrl.Name, CurrentLocale);
    foreach (Control control in ctrl.Controls)
        RefreshResources(control, res); // recursion
    ctrl.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

If you want a better example check [my blog](http://codeuntil.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/localizable-forms-in-c-or-how-to.html).

Answer (score 2):

This statements were helpful for me:

```
string myLanguage = "HE-IL";
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =
   InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(myLanguage));
```

Comment: this is great too, amending that first line, can do it for whatever country  http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm