# Change Writing Language Of Windows in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Language in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279403/change-language-in-c-sharp)

I want to change writing language to another Language that is set in "Region and Language".
How can I do it??

Or can I set new language in Region and Language of windows???

I tried this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

form [Change Language in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279403/change-language-in-c-sharp)
but It doesn't worked.

Comment: are you talking about keyborbord language?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this will help you:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3279403/change-language-in-c-sharp

Comment: It's better to flag the answer as duplicate.

Comment: guys he is not talking about that

Comment: @mekici what's his topic then?

Comment: he is talking about Region and Language of Windows, Forexample my system right now En (english) - Jp (japanese) so when i send email to my english friend johny i simply use alt+shift and write english words then when i send email to my friend Kobayashi again use that shortcuts and write japanese words. :) and even i m not orginally japanesse..

Comment: yes becouse you are not asking clearly your problem!!