# Access Windows input language from Chrome API

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a possibility to change input language in Windows OS from Chrome extension. Is it possible?

I have looked in the documentation, but cannot find the answer.

Could anyone help me with this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a nice plugin for FF https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tablang/ with no alternatives for Chrome which do this. When you use different languages in everyday life (English and Russian in my case), sometimes it is convenient to bind specific languages to specific sites (i.e. on SO I want English only, but in social network I use Russian).

Comment: Oh, I see now. I'm guessing the Firefox one executes some native binaries or something. I don't know about Chrome's API, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was sandboxed from these types of things.

Comment: Sad to hear it. Is there any workarounds for Chrome? Not Chrome API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome extension itself can't do this, since it is in sandbox.

You could use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to establish communication between extension and native applications, then in native app, you can call related windows methods to change OS language, refer to [Change Language in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279403/change-language-in-c-sharp) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comrehensive answer